Airflow sensor which checks if GCS object was updated
I would like to have a DAG which checks if avro file on GCS and if yes go to another task. This avro file comes to gcs under different names so i would like to use prefix to just get any avro file in the folder. I used code like this:
    gcs_sensor = GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor(  
        task_id='gcs_avro_file_sensor',  
        bucket='my_bucket',  
        prefix='mysql/abc/',   
        google_cloud_conn_id='google_cloud_default',  
        timeout=600,  
        poke_interval=60,  
        dag=dag  
    )  

but it always succeed as it is ExistenceSensor. How can I modify it to check if new file got updated there (old file is always removed so only 1 avro file is always in this folder).

from airflow documentation:

When files matching the given prefix are found, the poke method’s
criteria will be fulfilled

that means any file with this prefix.
from your question:

(old file is always removed so only 1 avro file is always in this folder).

This means ExistenceSensor should always return true. I'd suggest to use GCSObjectUpdateSensor after you get the file name from this PrefixExistenceSensor.
